# Android NDK and User Interface

Tags: android, user-interface, android-ndk

I currently have a purely native Android app using the Android NDK.

The entry point of my app must be in native code, because I need to access the input polling method provided via the android_app parameter, that is passed to android_main.

I do make a few calls into Java using JNI, however would there also be a way to access the Android SDK's UI capability (i.e. in Java) with this type of setup, or do I need to provide my own UI capability in native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call C++ and Java back and forth using JNI, so there should be no need to provide your own UI capabilities.